# C# game client with asyncronous sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, client

I'm developing a small online game in C#. Currently I am using simple sync TCP sockets. But now (because this is some kind of "learning project") I want to convert to asynchronous sockets. In the client I have the method: `byte[] SendAndReceive(Opcode op, byte[] data)`.
But when I use async sockets this isn't possible anymore. 
For example my `MapManager` class first checks if a map is locally in a folder (checksum) and if it isn't, the map will be downloaded from the server.

So my question:
Is there any good way to send some data and get the answer without saving the received data to some kind of buffer and polling till this buffer isn't null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out IO Completion Ports and the SocketAsyncEventArgs that goes with it. It raises events when data has been transferred, but you still need a buffer. Just no polling. It's fast and pretty efficient.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod

and another example on MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A code example of what you have would help, but I'd suggest using a new thread for each socket connection with a thread manager. Lmk if that makes sense or if that' applicable here. :)